# Client/Server communication over the internet using ZeroMQ

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, zeromq

I am new to zeroMQ. I am trying to develop a simple client server application and I am following the tutorials on zeroMQ’s website:

**Server:** http://zguide.zeromq.org/cs:wuserver

**Client:** http://zguide.zeromq.org/cs:wuclient

It’s working fine when I am trying to connect to the server using Local Host Loop Back IP(127.0.0.1) or internal LAN IP but when I attempt to connect over the Internet, i do not receive any messages on the client side.

I have a couple questions:

**1- Is this even possible? If not then is there any better way to implement the publisher/subscriber messaging model?**

**2- Am i doing anything wrong? Do i need to do something differently for communication over the internet?**

Hoping to get some positive feedback.

Regards.

Comment: Where do you run client and server? Any firewalls, NAT-devices between them?

Comment: On 2 separate machines. And yes, there is a router between them. The server as well as the client are behind routers. No explicit firewalls though.

Comment: What are the addresses? Public/private? Can you `telnet` to <server IP>/<server port> from the client machine?

Comment: Usually firewalls are present in any modern router. You usually have to setup the routers to allow connections to specific IPs on specific ports. i.e. Port Forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a firewall that has blocked external connections to the port you're using. You might try looking at the admin for your router () and opening a certain port to use for testing.